# NativeScript ListView isn't updating

Tags: android, listview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

So I have a ListView like this

```
     <ListView height="150" [items]="countries">
            <ng-template let-country="item">
                <Image src={{country.imgSrc}}></Image>
                <Label text={{country.name}}></Label>
            </ng-template>
     </ListView>
```

I have a subscription to an Observable that is returning an array of countries.

```
countries: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
   this.countryService.countriesUpdated.subscribe(
      (countries:any[]) => {
           this.countries = countries;
       {
   )
}
```

When countries is updated. The ListView doesn't update the screen with a new ListItem. If instead I initialize countries with a value, it does display the ListItem. I placed a button on the screen with a tap listener, that console.log(this.countries). After the tap, the new ListItem finally appears. Shouldn't the binding of countries to the ListView automatically update?

NativeScript 6.0
Android 10

Comment: If it works on tap, then I guess the change detection didn't work properly at earlier point. Can you share a minimal Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added private zone `NgZone` to my constructor, and then wrapped the subscription response like this:

```
this.zone.run(()=>{
   me.countries= countries;
});
```

Source: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/listview-does-not-refresh-update-when-a-new-value-is-added/1492

Answer (score 0):

Typically in this scenario you'll need to invoke refresh().  I don't use angular, in in javascript this would be something like,

```
page.getViewById("listview").refresh();
```

and have an id=listview such as

```
<ListView id-"listview" height="150" [items]="countries">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a **RxObservable subscription** to populate your items. That would mean that you need to use the [**async** pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). For example, [see here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/rovers/rovers.component.html#L4) the async pipe is used here for the list's ***items*** property and how in the code behind you are populating the items in the subscription ([here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/rovers/rovers.component.ts#L21) and [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/rovers/rovers.component.ts#L84-L87)).